No property found for validation: [g-recaptcha-response] biscolab / laravel-recaptcha
My project was written with Livewire
For Google Recaptcha, I use https://github.com/biscolab/laravel-recaptcha
This is the code of the controller:
class ContactForm extends Component
{
    public $name;
    public $email;
    public $phone;
    public $message;
    
    protected $rules = [
        'name' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'phone' => 'required',
        'message' => 'required',
        'g-recaptcha-response' => 'recaptcha',
    ];


    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.contact-form');
    }

    public function save(){
        $this->validate();
        Contact::create([
            'name' => $this->name,
            'email' => $this->email,
            'phone' => $this->phone,
            'message' => $this->message,
        ]);
        session()->flash('status', 'Thanks!');
    }
}

This HTML form code:
<form id="contact_form" wire:submit="save" method="post" id="dreamit-form" class="@if ( Config::get('app.locale') == 'fa') text-right @endif">
    @csrf

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <div class="form_box mb-30">
                <input type="text" wire:model="name"  placeholder="{{ __('messages.contactPage_form_input_fullname') }}" >
                @error('name') <span class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</span> @enderror
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <div class="form_box mb-30">
                <input type="email" wire:model="email" placeholder="{{ __('messages.contactPage_form_input_email') }}" >
                @error('email') <span class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</span> @enderror
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <div class="form_box mb-30">
                <input type="text" wire:model="phone" placeholder="{{ __('messages.contactPage_form_input_phone') }}" >
                @error('phone') <span class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</span> @enderror
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="form_box mb-30">
                <textarea wire:model="message" id="message" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="{{ __('messages.contactPage_form_input_message') }}" ></textarea>
                @error('message') <span class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</span> @enderror
            </div>
            {!! htmlFormSnippet() !!}
            <div class="quote_btn">
                <button class="btn" type="submit">{{ __('messages.contactPage_form_btn_submit') }}</button>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</form>

And this error that I receive after registering the form:

No property found for validation: [g-recaptcha-response]

please guide me

The $rules must be applied to the public properties binded to the frontend inputs and managed by Livewire.
Unfortunately g-recaptcha-response is not a valid PHP identifier.
Since the biscolab/laravel-recaptcha package allows a callback which receives the wanted token as parameter, we can use it to fill a property:
The class
class ContactForm extends Component
{
    public $name;
    public $email;
    public $phone;
    public $message;
    public $gRecaptchaResponse;  // <~~~ this property will contain the token

    protected $rules = [

        'name' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'phone' => 'required',
        'message' => 'required',
        'gRecaptchaResponse' => 'recaptcha',
    ];

    .....


The view
<form .....>

    .....

    {!! htmlFormSnippet(['callback' => 'setGRecaptchaResponse']) !!} // <~~~ let's declare the callback

    .....

</form>

<script>
 
    function setGRecaptchaResponse(token)  {
        @this.gRecaptchaResponse = token;  // <~~~ this fills the Livewire property
    }

</script>

Note:
since Livewire provides the csrf itself, you can omit it from the form

Important note:
The biscolab/laravel-recaptcha package is marked as abandoned / no longer maintained so be careful using it as it may stop working or cause problems in the future
